# MVC3 Editable Grids

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, grid

I have a requirement to use an editable grid in my MVC3 project.  (i.e., the grid needs to add rows, delete rows, edit cells within each row).  I've tried Telerik but the documentation seems to be primarily MVC2 and I found it difficult to understand.  Does anyone know of a decent MVC2 Edittable grid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than looking for an "MVC Grid" you'd probably have more luck searching for a JQuery (or other javascript grid) that fits your needs. Most MVC grids you will find are merely wrapping a jquery grid in a helper class to make things more convenient for .NET developers. [Here](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-grids/) are some examples of nice JQuery grids. I've personally used Flexigrid and (while documentation is sparse) it is pretty easy to use

Comment: @JP...I looked at the site but couldn't tell if they were editable grids or not.  That's what I need.  Are they, do you know?

Comment: I'm not sure if all of these do, but JQGrid http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html certainly does and is pretty sweet

Answer (score 2):

Look at the knockout editable collection samples, it may give you some ideas as well:

http://knockoutjs.com/examples/gridEditor.html

Its client side only, and you can just serialize your JSON back to the server and it will automatically be interpreted by the ModelBinder and deserialized in to your model class.  This eliminates having to go back to the server for anything between row inserts, deletes, etc.